# pandas pivot table how to rearrange columns

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas df which I am looking to build a pivot table with.
Here is a sample table

```
Name   Week   Category     Amount

ABC     1     Clothing      50
ABC     1     Food          10
ABC     1     Food          10
ABC     1     Auto          20
DEF     1     Food          10
DEF     1     Services      20
```

The pivot table I am looking to create is to sum up the amounts per Name, per week per category.
Essentially, I am looking to land up with a table as follows:

```
Name  Week   Clothing   Food   Auto   Services   Total
ABC    1      50         20     20     0          90
DEF    1      0          10     0      20         30
```

If a user has no category value in a particular week, I take it as `0`
And the total is the row sum.

I tried some of the options mentioned at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html but couldnt get it to work...any thoughts on how I can achieve this. I used
`df.pivot_table(values=['Amount'], index=['Name','Week','Category'], aggfunc=[np.sum])`  followed by `df.unstack()` but that did not yield the desired result as both `Week` and `Category` got unstacked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(index = [df['Name'],df['Week']],
                  columns = df['Category'],
                  values=df['Amount'],
                  margins=True,
                  aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).iloc[:-1].reset_index()
Category Name Week  Auto  Clothing  Food  Services  All
0         ABC    1  20.0      50.0  20.0       0.0   90
1         DEF    1   0.0       0.0  10.0      20.0   30
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df_pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Amount', index = ['Name', 'Week'], columns = 'Category', aggfunc = np.sum, margins=True, margins_name = 'Total', fill_value = 0
df_pvt.columns.name = None
df_pvt = df_pvt.reset_index()
```